# Assigning a variable inside an array

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress site and I need to assign the value of a function to a value inside an array but it keeps giving me errors. In the customFields array I need to insert the value of the get_option('contact_email', 'no one') into some helper text. In the code snippet below I need to replace {CONTACT_EMAIL} with the get_option value but can't figure it out.

...

```
    var $customFields = array(
        array(
            "name"          => "ContactPerson-name",
            "title"         => "Contact Name",
            "description"   => "Enter the first and last name of the page contact. If left blank, the site default of {CONTACT_PERSON} will be used.",
            "type"          => "textinput",
            "scope"         =>  array( "page" ),
            "capability"    => "edit_pages"
        ),
        array(
            "name"          => "ContactPerson-email",
            "title"         => "Contact Email",
            "description"   => "Enter the email address of the page contact. If left blank, the site default of {CONTACT_EMAIL} will be used.",
            "type"          => "textinput",
            "scope"         =>  array( "page" ),
            "capability"    => "edit_pages"
        ),

        array(
            "name"          => "ContactPerson-phone",
            "title"         => "Contact Phone (XXX) XXX-XXXX",
            "description"   => "Enter the phone number of the page contact. If left blank, the site default of {CONTACT_PHONE} will be used.",
            "type"          => "textinput",
            "scope"         =>  array( "page" ),
            "capability"    => "edit_pages"
        ),

        array(
            "name"          => "ContactPerson-address",
            "title"         => "Contact Room Number &amp; Building",
            "description"   => "Enter the room number and building of the page contact. Click <a href=\"http://www.engin.umich.edu/buildingabbreviations\">here</a> for building abbreviations. If left blank, the site default of {CONTACT_ADDRESS} will be used.",
            "type"          => "textinput",
            "scope"         =>  array( "page" ),
            "capability"    => "edit_pages"
        ),
```

...

...

I've tried to close the text and concat the function, I've tried to do a string replace and nothing seems to work. Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: did you try to use something like:
$contactEmail = get_option('contact_email', 'no one');

array(...."title" => $contactEmail),

Comment: Have you included the files needed to to use that function?

Comment: @deceze, the famous white screen of death, but my UI was telling me there was a code error

Comment: If get_Option will return array, you can use `implode` and store it on `CONTACT_EMAIL` variable

Comment: @cptnk, guess I should mention that its an array inside an array

Comment: Show your attempt with the function written, then we could adjust your code

Comment: `array(
            "name"          => "ContactPerson-email",
            "title"         => "Contact Email",
            "description"   => "Enter the email address of the page contact. If left blank, the site default of ".get_option('contact_email','no one')." will be used.",
            "type"          => "textinput",
            "scope"         =>  array( "page" ),
            "capability"    => "edit_pages"
        ),`

Comment: I also set the string up outside the arrays and then tried to use the variable as the value, but also got errors.

$emailString = "Enter the email address of the page contact. If left blank, the site default of ".get_option('contact_email','no one')." will be used.";

Then:  "description" => $emailString

Comment: what kind of error are you getting when u try to get the value out of the array?

Comment: Please post the complete error messages

Comment: cptnk, I am just getting a white screen. I tried to show errors, but nothing is showing error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute force method will work...

```
$customFields = array(
    array(
        "name"          => "ContactPerson-name",
        "title"         => "Contact Name",
        "description"   => "... of {CONTACT_PERSON} will be used...",
        "type"          => "textinput",
        "scope"         =>  array( "page" ),
        "capability"    => "edit_pages"
    )
);

$contact_person = get_option('contact_person');

foreach($customFields as &$field)
{
    $field['description'] = str_replace("{CONTACT_PERSON}", $contact_person, $field['description']);
}

unset($field);
```

Comment: Yeah, I did something just like that and it worked. But lead me to a new issue...getting the right value from the get_option() function..